# Plesk and Zend Mysql Error

Tags: php, mysql, plesk

i need help yesterday i would install Zend .

I have copy the Files on server and move this to PHP modules.

Now after restart i become this :

```
ERROR: Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Additionally, an exception has occurred while trying to report this error: Zend_Exception
No entry is registered for key &#039;translate&#039; (Abstract.php:144)

Search for related Knowledge Base articles

ERROR: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129 Stack trace: #0 /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=ps...', 'admin', '$AES-128-CBC$ib...', Array) #1 /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2 /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3 /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('select param, v...', Array) #4 /opt/psa/admin/plib/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(30): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('select param, v...', Array) #5 /opt/psa/admin/plib/db.php(36): Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('select param, v...') #6 /opt/psa/admin/plib/db.php(212): db_query('select param, v...', false) #7 /opt/psa/admin/plib/Plesk/Mode.php(439): get_param('disable_provisi...') #8 /opt/psa/admin (Abstract.php:144)
```

My Mysql Show this :

```
2017-09-06T11:21:12.608312Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2017-09-06T11:21:12.608364Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2017-09-06T11:21:12.772598Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-09-06T11:21:12.772621Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2017-09-06T11:21:12.774366Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 17662 ...
2017-09-06T11:21:12.778244Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-09-06T11:21:12.778269Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-09-06T11:21:12.778275Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-09-06T11:21:12.778281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-09-06T11:21:12.778285Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-09-06T11:21:12.778289Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-09-06T11:21:12.778526Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-09-06T11:21:12.778630Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-09-06T11:21:12.781046Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-09-06T11:21:12.788945Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-09-06T11:21:12.790924Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-09-06T11:21:12.802537Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Only one log file found.
2017-09-06T11:21:12.802553Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error not found
2017-09-06T11:21:13.402971Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-09-06T11:21:13.402997Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-09-06T11:21:13.403004Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-09-06T11:21:13.403008Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

ZF1? Check application.ini credentials, and make sure your MySQL server is actually running and can accept a connection from remotes if on a different server

Comment: how can remove this Zend ?